# how to encode a json string in object list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a problem i can't understand what's going wrong please help.

I saw this awnser but my problem doesn't solve.
[Flutter Json Encode List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024549/flutter-json-encode-list)

here is json String:   [{id: 4, quantity: 1, name: Implant, price: 7000}]

```
Services.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    quantity = json['quantity'];
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'];
  }

    print(_billModel.services);
    Iterable<dynamic> l = json.decode(_billModel.services.trim());

    var services = l.map((value) => Services.fromJson(value)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this keyword

```
    Services.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.id = json['id'];
    this.quantity = json['quantity'];
    this.name = json['name'];
    this.price = json['price'];
  }
    print(_billModel.services);
    Iterable<dynamic> l = json.decode(_billModel.services.trim());

    var services = l.map((value) => Services.fromJson(value)).toList();
```

You want to encode jsonstring then use the following method

```
 Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(jsonString);

print('Howdy, ${user['name']}!');
print('We sent the verification link to ${user['email']}.');
```

for inside models class

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
    {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
    };
}
```

- A User.fromJson() constructor, for constructing a new User instance
  from a map structure.
- A toJson() method, which converts a User instance into a map.

> The responsibility of the decoding logic is now moved inside the model
>   itself. With this new approach, you can decode a user easily.

```
Map userMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
var user = User.fromJson(userMap);

print('Howdy, ${user.name}!');
print('We sent the verification link to ${user.email}.');
```

> To encode a user, pass the User object to the jsonEncode() function.
>   You don’t need to call the toJson() method, since jsonEncode() already
>   does it for you.

```
String json = jsonEncode(user);
```

For more information , read this article from [flutter.io](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#manual-encoding)

Comment: hope you find the edited one usefull. if not let me know