# How to post line_items in json file through woocommerce rest api?

Tags: flutter, woocommerce-rest-api

I've successfully used rest api of woocommerce in my flutter app but I'm stuck at one point which is adding line_items in json file through woocommerce rest API.

```
List<CartPdt>linecartitems=[];
linecartitems.map((i)=>{
  'product_id':int.parse(i.id),
  'quantity':i.quantity
}).toList();

var lc=json.encode(linecartitems);

var createOrderUrl = await http.post(
    'url',
    body: json.encode({
      'billing': {
        'first_name': fname,
        'last_name': lname,
        'email': email,
        'address': address,
        'city': city,
        'phone': phone
      },
      'line_items':lc,
    }),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  );
```

Comment: Please clarify the error or the issue you faced with.

Comment: "line_items":"line_items[0] is not of type object. This is the error I'm getting.

Comment: You can look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025048/10659482

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your list model to JSON. I assume that you have not got `toJson` method in your model. Add this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
  return {
    "product_id": this. product_id,
    "quantity": this. quantity
  };
}
```

Comment: No., I've added toJson and fromJson method in CartPdt class..